# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "order_id" violates not-null constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure in postgresql as follows:

```
 INSERT INTO ABC

     (order_id,order_dt, customer_id, route_id, routenum, ordertype, create_station_id, create_stationtype, create_time,create_user_id,tran_time, tran_user_id,station_id)

   values 

     (1,$1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, LOCALTIMESTAMP, $8, 

    default, default,$9) 

   returning  order_id;
```

There `order_id` is type of `SERIAL` -> `primary key`

I am getting error while insertion as follows:

```
PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "order_id" violates not-null constraint Where: SQL function "insert_ABC" statement 1.
```

I am using `PostgreSQL 8.2`. It is in a hosting space I am doing this.

I know error occurs because the default type takes null as default.

What is the equivalent of `default` of type `SERIAL`.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

You could skip `order_id` in `INSERT INTO`:

```
CREATE TABLE ABC(order_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, order_dt INT -- rest of cols
                );

INSERT INTO ABC(order_dt)  -- rest of cols
VALUES (2)                 -- rest of values
RETURNING order_id;
```

or use `default`:

```
INSERT INTO ABC(order_id, order_dt)
VALUES (default, 2)
RETURNING order_id;
```

**EDIT:**

Are you sure? Check demo:

```
CREATE TABLE ABC(order_id SERIAL, order_dt INT);

INSERT INTO ABC(order_dt)  -- rest of cols
VALUES (2) ;  

INSERT INTO ABC(order_id, order_dt)
VALUES (default, 2) ;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2b360/1/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═══════════╦══════════╗
║ order_id  ║ order_dt ║
╠═══════════╬══════════╣
║        1  ║        2 ║
║        2  ║        2 ║
╚═══════════╩══════════╝
```

Trying to execute  with SQLFiddle:

```
CREATE TABLE ABC(order_id SERIAL NULL, order_dt INT);
-- ERROR: conflicting NULL/NOT NULL declarations for 
-- column "order_id" of table "abc"
```

I don't have environment to test it with `PostgreSQL 8.2` but if it is allowed to define order_id with `NULL` you should alter schema to `NOT NULL`

Comment: `default` wont work because it is getting `NULL` value, and here `order_id` is a primary key and not null.